# Clarification on the "tickets in a box interpretation" for random variables

Tags: sampling, random-variable, randomness

I have a question on the definition of a random variable. I have read the **tickets in a box interpretation** [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-is-meant-by-a-random-variable/54894#54894) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224442/how-to-understand-the-relationships-among-random-variables-samples-and-populat), which helped me immensely, but I have some doubts for the case in which the population is infinite. **In particular, I am confused on what is the relation among infinite population-continuous/discrete random variables-measurability-zero probability events.**

Following the discussion in the linked answer, suppose that my population $\Omega$ is an **infinite** list of paper slips (a generic paper slip is denoted by $\omega$) and in each paper slip I write numbers, e.g.,

```
            X  Y epsilon
paperslip1  5  1 0.5

paperslip1  5  0 0.2

paperslip1  6  0 0.3

...
```

---

**1):** In order to understand the measurability condition in the definition of a random variable, we firstly need to say which measure we are using. We need a probability measure, which a denote by $P: \mathcal{\Omega}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{\mathcal{F}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. How do we construct it? The first naively idea that comes to my mind is by using the **counting measure**, e.g., assuming $\{5\}\in \mathcal{F}$
$$
P(\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } X(\omega)\in \{5\})\equiv\frac{\text{ # paper slips with $5$ written on them}}{\text{# paper slips}}=\frac{\text{some number, not necessarily finite}}{\infty}=0 \text{ or }\frac{\infty}{\infty}
$$
This is clearly not a probability measure. Hence, using the counting measure is wrong when we have an infinite population. Correct?

---

**2):** If my arguments in **1)** are correct, then we need to find another way to construct a probability measure. The second idea that comes to my mind is by using the **length measure**, e.g., assuming $\{5\}\in \mathcal{F}$
$$
P(\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } X(\omega)\in \{5\})\equiv\frac{\text{ Length of paper slips with $5$ written on them}}{\text{Length paper slips}}=\frac{\text{some finite number}}{\text{some finite number}}\in [0,1]
$$
We can easily verify that all the properties that a probability measure should have are satisfied. Correct? Also, is it true that the length measure is always finite?

---

**3):** If my arguments in 2) are correct, could you help me to understand what is $\mathcal{F}$? It seems to me that all events are length measurable.

---

**4):** Within this context, is it correct to define continuous random variables, as random variables for which the length of singleton sets in $\mathcal{F}$ is zero? And, conversely, discrete random variables, as random variables for which the length of singleton sets in $\mathcal{F}$ is strictly positive?

Comment: The tickets-in-a-box model is an exceedingly accurate *conceptual* model.  It is not intended to support the (usually misunderstood) concept of "infinitely many" tickets.  Fortunately, such a concept is not needed.  Standard mathematics usually avoids it altogether by taking limits.  There is a branch of probability theory based on nonstandard analysis which doesn't require infinities at all: *every* "box" truly is finite.  See http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/nsa/.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Are you say, e.g.,  that there is no easy way to conceptualise (in a sampling approach to inference) continuous random variables using  an framework similar to the tickets-in-a-box model? Do we necessarily have to go to nonstandard analysis? Or, is the limit thing that you are mentioning, a possible easy way to proceed?

Comment: And if the limit approach can help me, could you walk me through?

Comment: I would love to, but I probably don't have the time right now.  There's a wonderful account of the process for a particular example in Steven Shreve [*Stochastic Calculus for Finance* Vol. I](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387401003).  Volume II, where measure theory is (finally) introduced, formalizes it and shows the connections between this limiting process and filtrations of sigma algebras.

Comment: thanks, as I have to buy the book: is it volume I or II?

Comment: If you could also suggest me the chapter of the book  I should mostly focus on, I would be immensely grateful. I don't know anything of finance, time processes, etc, and the book seems focus on that.

Comment: Read chapter 2: it's available as a free PDF from the Springer site I linked to.  That will quickly tell you whether the level and style of this text is to your liking.