# What are "prior distribution" and "posterior distribution" in the case of Bayesian statistics?

Tags: distributions, bayesian

What are "prior distribution" and "posterior distribution" in the case of Bayesian statistics?

Can you give layman's examples?

I understand prior and posterior **probabilities**. However, I don't know "**distribution**".

Comment: I think you have it switched: when we say priors, we mean prior probability distributions. Priors are always defined as distributions.

Comment: @Firebug you can write down [Bayes theorem for events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#For_events) so your comment may be unclear without further clarification.

Comment: By "distribution" do you mean densities (PDFs)? If yes, then the question of deriving Bayes' formula for densities from probabilities is indeed not trivial (see Papoulis 2002. Probabilities Random Variables and Stochastic Processes. Chp4-4). But if you mean CDFs then Bayes' theorem for CDFs follows immediately from Bayes' theorem for probabilities since CDFs are probabilities (i.e. needs only replacing the event with the random variable e.g. $P(A)$ with $P(X\le x)$).

Comment: @Tim since it's about Bayesian statistics I thought it followed directly from that definition, and not for the general Bayes' Theorem, which is not exclusively Bayesian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior probability vs distribution is the same distinction as between [probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) (in general) and [probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution). Probability is a number between 0 and 1, the probability distribution is a function $f(x)$ that maps some values $x$ to corresponding probabilities. Probabilities are usually not very interesting because they refer to binary events *probability that $A$ is true* $P(A)$, while probability distributions generalize this concept e.g. *probability that after rolling a $K$-sided dice you'd observe $4$ as a result,* $P(X=4)$. This introduces another concept: [*random variables*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224442/how-to-understand-the-relationships-among-random-variables-samples-and-populat). If those things are not familiar to you, I recommend a probability theory [course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2SOU6wwxB0uwwH80KTQ6ht66KWxbzTIo) or a [handbook](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239431/book-recommendations-for-probability).

Bayes theorem is

$$ \underbrace{p(\theta \mid X)}_\text{posterior} = \frac{\overbrace{p(X \mid \theta)}^\text{likelihood} \, \overbrace{p(\theta)}^\text{prior}}{\underbrace{p(X)}_\text{normalizing constant}} $$

*Prior* is the unconditional probability of $\theta$ that you know *a priori*, given the data in *likelihood* it is updated so that you end up with conditional *posterior*. Next, you could use this posterior as a prior with new data, this is called [Bayesian updating](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237037/bayesian-updating-with-new-data/237109#237109).

See also [Help me understand Bayesian prior and posterior distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/help-me-understand-bayesian-prior-and-posterior-distributions).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you wonder about the percentage of likely voters who
would currently
vote for Candadate X in an upcoming election.
X seems to get more favorable press than his opponent, but
there have not yet been any professionally conducted polls.

Because elections for this office often tend to be close, you
might think a reasonable prior distribution for X's
share $p$ of the vote would be $\mathsf{Beta}(35, 30).$

This prior distribution has mean $\mu = 35/65 = 7/13 =  0.5385,$ and
about 95% of its probability in the interval $(0.42, 0.66),$
and density function $f(x) \propto p^{36}(1-p)^{31}.$
where the symbol $\propto$ (read "proportional to")
indicates that we have written the 'kernel' of the prior
distribution without the "norming" constant that makes it
integrate to unity over $(0,1).$ (The normalizing constant in @Tim's answer does not need to be evaluated.)

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 35,30)
[1] 0.4174763 0.6572035
```

Admittedly, many other similar prior distributions might
have been chosen, but Bayesian statistics allows 'personal'
probabilities, and this prior distribution, which gives
a slight edge to Candidate X, while coming nowhere near
suggesting he is sure to win, seems about right to you.

Next, suppose a reliable poll of $n = 500$
randomly chosen voters shows $x = 335$ in favor of
Candidate X. This binomial likelihood function
$$g(x|p) = {500 \choose 335}p^{335}(1 - p)^{165}
\propto p^{335}(1 - p)^{165}.$$

[In frequentist statistics, the maximum likelihood
estimate of $p$ based only on the poll would be $\hat p = 335/500 =  0.67.]$

According to Bayes' Theorem, the posterior distribution of $p$
is found by multiplying the prior distribution by the
likelihood function
$$h(p|x)\, =\, f(p)\times g(x|p)\, \propto\,
p^{36}(1-p)^{31} \times p^{335}(1 - p)^{165}\\
\propto\, p^{391}(1-p)^{196},$$

where we recognize the final member above as the kernel
of the distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(390, 195).$
Thus the posterior mean is $390/(290+196) \approx  0.802$
and a 95% posterior probability interval (credible interval)
is $(0.608, 0.688).$ So, at this stage of the campaign
Candidate X has a very comfortable lead.

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975),360,195)
[1] 0.6084775 0.6878051
```

The relatively uninformative prior has less influence
on the posterior distribution than does the poll of 500
potential voters. However,
the Bayesian credible interval applies to the current
election. If we believe the prior distribution was
realistic and that the poll is carefully done and free
of bias, we can believe the credible interval.

---

*Notes:* (1) The beta prior distribution and the
binomial likelihood are of compatible algebraic form.
One says that they are *conjugate.* In this example,
conjugacy makes it easy to find the posterior
distribution.

(2) An Agresti-Cooil 95% CI for $p$ based only on
the likelihood would be $(0.628, 0.710).$
But many frequentists would not associate this CI
directly with the current election, but with
the long run behavior of similar elections.

```
p.est = 337/504
p.est + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/504)
[1] 0.6275571 0.7097445
```