# Does a single observation from a population have the same distribution as that population?

Tags: sampling, density-function, beta-distribution

Suppose X1 is one observation from a population with Beta(θ,1) PDF. Would X1 also have Beta(θ,1) PDF?

Answer (score 1):

As you can learn from the [How to Understand the Relationships Among Random Variables, Samples, and Populations?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224442/how-to-understand-the-relationships-among-random-variables-samples-and-populat) thread,

> A **population** is usually modeled as a set $\mathcal S$ together with a *probability measure* $\mathbb{P}$ on that set.  [...]
> A (univariate) **random variable** $X:\mathcal{S}\to\mathbb{R}$ assigns numbers to the *elements* of $\mathcal S$. [...]

and **sampling** is commonly understood in statistics as

> [...] Another procedure focuses on a random variable, rather than the population, and views an *independent and identically distributed* ("iid") sample as a sequence $$X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$$ of random variables on $\mathcal S$ (a) that are independent and (b) for which all the $X_i$ have the same distribution.

So a sample of size $n$ is thought as a sequence of random variables

$$X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$$

all following the same distribution, "coming from" the same population. The population does not "have" distribution, random variables do. You are mixing different concepts, so I highly recommend the linked thread that discusses it in depth.